# How do I locate a vacuum hose in 1993 Buick Regal for heating system

Tags: buick, heater-control, vacuum-hoses, regal

The heater ducts on a 1993 Buick Regal are not working ~ they are stuck on defrost. I suspect a vacuum leak is causing the issue ~ where is the vacuum hose located so I can verify this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: usually runs along the passenger side of the engine bay.

Answer (score 3):

If i remember right there is a vacuum solenoid box under the dash on the passenger side, they are notorious for the hoses and connectors inside the box to disintegrate, you can open the box and re plumb it. You can follow the vacuum lines as all the actuator lines go into it. Be sure to take a picture of the inside before you start repairs.

First check the vacuum supply line under the hood is intact, it will go from the intake manifold thru the firewall. Small diameter plastic line, usually black.

[image]

Comment: If it is the solenoid box and you dont want to repair it, rockauto has one for $56.70. AC Delco PN1572182....https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/buick,1993,regal,3.8l+v6,1021239,heat+&+air+conditioning,a/c+vacuum+control+valve,7036

Comment: Where does the supply line go through the firewall?

Comment: Not sure, somewhere on the passenger side near the top. It will be the only vacuum line going through the firewall. If it is black it might look like a wire since it is so small diameter. (1/8")